# How to communicate between same application installed on two android handset?

Tags: android

I want to interact between two android enabled handset with same application installed,  but i dont want to use any web service.

Is this possible even if i know the recipent mobile number?
If there is any way to do that then please tell me. you can also send me the link of the webpage.

Comment: do you want **near filed interaction** or **far field interaction** between two android powered handsets? why you mentioned the recipient mobile number ?

Comment: I thought if i know the recipent mobile number and know that he is using the same application then it might be possible to communicate between two app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the devices are close enough, take a look at blutooth communication. Most Android devices are equipped with those.

If the devices are not near each other, you could implement a Sms parser.

But maybe if you tell us why you don't want to use internet, we could better understand your use case.

Comment: If i use internet to send the data from my app to same app installed on another handset then my app user will be charged for using internet. and if they dont use the internet then my app become useless for them.

Answer (score 1):

Use content providers, when you create it you will get a content URI from where you can access data between two apps. Its the same way your android contacts manager provide you contacts. Android dev link

[Android dev link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html)

Comment: As I understand it, the OP asks about communication between two different handset, not between apps on the same device. I could be mistaken though :)

Comment: yeah, tats correct i dint observe the question completely. thanks for correcting me yahel

Answer (score 0):

Why Not use NFC for the purpose, please see link:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/nfc/nfc.html

Comment: this will not help in my problem if two of my app user are far away from each other.

Comment: you should agree that there must be some medium by which applications interact on different devices. Internet/SMS might be used if there is no assumption of cost or availability of internet and sms.

Answer (score 0):

For phones running Android 4.0 or later, there's WiFi Direct:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html