# Is it possible to communicate between two android phones?

Tags: android, networking

I already read following question and answers.

[How to communicate between same application installed on two android handset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9001779/how-to-communicate-between-same-application-installed-on-two-android-handset)

I think the use case is totally same as mine.

But I still have a remaining question - what does 'using internet' in the article above mean between two phones each far away?

I think I need some more explanation in detail.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you considered making a call or sending a text message?

Comment: @StealthRabbi I don't know which method is better. If it's using SMS, isn't it inconvenient to user?
If you're ok, could I ask some article about sending data using SMS?

Comment: I think Stealth Rabbi was being sarcastic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, two applications can talk over the internet (or bluetooth or sms/mms for that matter, but less practical). Just like any two computers can communicate over the internet. There's a wide variety of protocols. A whole world really. Do you need references to some tutorials on networking or am I totally missing your question?

EDIT: You can try [The TCP/IP Guide](http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/index.htm) for an intro

EDIT: And for android you probably want to use their [socket interface](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Socket.html)

UPDATE: About how to communicate between clients - you probably don't want to rely on knowing a particular peer's IP address. Usually what you do is work with some known host as a server, which coordinates between the peers, sometimes relaying the messages between them, or alternatively just notifying the clients about each other's addresses.

Comment: Thanks very much and may I ask some tutorials? In case of PCs, they have IP addresses, but I don't know how is it possible between mobile devices because they are moving and IP addresses will be changed (if it's on 3G or not).

Comment: There's no problem with IP addresses because normally you don't roam into different cellular providers (you stay on your network, just roam between towers and exchanges). The provider supplies the IP routing on top of the cellular layer, so the same IP address can be used.

Comment: I see. So, you mean IP of phone is permanent? However, how can it be enabled to get IP address of a phone from another phone (for example, is it possible using phone number)?

Comment: I don't think the IP address is absolutely permanent, but perhaps it stays the same for the duration of a phone's connection to the cellular network (as long as the phone is on, for example). It also may differ for different cellular technologies (GPRS vs. LTE, for example).

Comment: @sinelaw can you give me an example of the hosts that coordintate between peers?

Comment: @FerasSalim I'm pretty sure Skype works that way: the server coordinates between clients, but once the video call is connected most of the data flows directly between clients